# How to use JavaScript to copy inner HTML, but without html shorthand?

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

I have a JS function that dynamically fills the inner HTML of a div with id="code-output" with some sample HTML code:

```
function outputCode() {
    var style = "<p>#main-container {</p><p class='indent-1'>width: 100%;</p><p>}</p>"

    var body = "<p>&ltdiv id='main-container'&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&ltdiv id='header'&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&lth1&gtThis is a header 1&lt/h1&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&lt/div&gt</p>" + "<p>&lt/div&gt</p>"

    code = "<p>&lt!DOCTYPE html&gt</p>" + "<p>&lthtml&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&lthead&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&ltmeta charset='utf-8'&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&ltmeta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&lttitle&gtMy HTML Theme&lt/title&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&ltstyle&gt</p>" + "<div class='code'>" + style + "</div>" + "<p class='indent-2'>&lt/style&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&lt/head&gt</p>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&ltbody&gt</p>" + "<div class='code'>" + body + "</div>" + "<p class='indent-1'>&lt/body&gt</p>" + "<p>&lt/html&gt</p>"

    outputBlock = document.getElementById("code-output");

    outputBlock.innerHTML = code;
}
```

Everything is static at the moment but I plan to have style and body be defined dynamically. Everything is working fine and the sample HTML code fills into the div as expected.

However, I would like to include a button to copy the sample HTML code to clipboard. I have a function to do this:

```
function copyHtml() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);

    document.getElementById("copied-message").innerHTML = "Copied";
}
```

This copies all of the code, but the problem is that it copies with the HTML shorthand and I need it to copy with regular tags (e.g. `<html></html>`, not &lthtml&gt &lt/html&gt).

Please let me know if there is any way to copy the text without the shorthand?

I have tried the above functions and it ends up copying as &lthtml&gt instead of `<html>`, for example.

Comment: Step 1: rewrite this from plain strings to [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which support line breaks, so you can actually read and have it future proofed for when you need to start putting values inside your strings. And bonus points for not doing this, but instead [using `<template>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) on your page that you tap into instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - thank you for bringing up template strings, I'm using those now and my code is much more readable and future proof, like you said. Can you explain a bit more on the "using `<template>` elements" part of your comment?

Comment: Rather than putting long strings in your JS, you write out your code inside`<template>` elements on the page itself, then you create instance of that template using JS. The MDN article does a pretty good job at showing how that all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to assign a String where you should be assigning an HTML node.

"innerText" is what you're looking for.

```
document.getElementById("copied-message").innerText = "Copied";
```

innerHTML is expecting an instance of an element already existing in the DOM. You can test this out by cloning an element already in the DOM and setting the innerHTMl value to the copy of that element.

Comment: I forgot to add. Try pasting the copied results into an empty notepad or any plain old text field. Do you still get the encoded HTML entities? You shouldn't but if you do please let me know as I'm curious if different browsers and OS return different results.

Comment: I forgot to add. Try pasting the copied results into an empty notepad or any plain old text field. Do you still get the encoded HTML entities? You shouldn't but if you do please let me know as I'm curious if different browsers and OS return different results.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do, use innerText instead of innerHTML. I can confirm that this works in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `HTMLElement.innerText`, but I'm linking you to the MDN documentation for [`HTMLElement.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) because it discusses some of the nuances between the two.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I was writing the sample code to the div's innerHTML, which is why I needed to use &lt and &gt instead of < and >. Using innerText, I am able to write the tags normally and copy them to clipboard normally as well!

Answer (score 0):

function copyHtml() {
var copyText = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML;

```
// Create a temporary textarea element
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

// Set its value to the text you want to copy, with regular tags
textarea.value = copyText.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");

// Append the textarea to the document
document.body.appendChild(textarea);

// Select the text and copy it to the clipboard
textarea.select();
document.execCommand("copy");

// Remove the temporary textarea
document.body.removeChild(textarea);

document.getElementById("copied-message").innerHTML = "Copied";
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this was solved more easily by just using `document.getElementById("code-output").innerText` rather than `document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML`